# Tika server returned 500 status code when processing a pdf file

Tags: apache-tika, tika-server, tika-python

**Code :**

```
dd= parser.from_file(r"file_path")
```

Line number 554 in tika .py

```
resp = verbFn(serviceUrl, encodedData, **effectiveRequestOptions)
```

Reason in resp was INKApi Error.

I am running tika server on my system.

Comment: What errors are in the Tika Server log for the troublesome request?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use the docker image to have tika-server up and running:

```bash
docker run -d -p 9998:9998 apache/tika:1.28.2-full
```

Once you got the image running could you try to open the file like this?

```py
from tika import parser

os.environ['TIKA_SERVER_ENDPOINT'] = 'http://0.0.0.0:9998/'

with open('path/to/file', 'rb') as file:
    data = parser.from_file(file)
```